# HttpWebRequest No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I am unable to make a successful HttpWebRequest in C# without the following error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:8888

If I use a proxy, I can make a request just fine, but when I turn off my proxy I can't make any request.

I have been using Fiddler and do think it's related but I can't find the solution. If I turn on Fiddler, I am able to make this request...

I have reviewed the web.configs and machine.configs but still no dice. I've also reviewed my Internet Options proxy settings in IE and Chrome (just to be sure).

Answer (score 0):

Yes: when fiddler starts it opens a listening port on 8888 on the local machine (127.0.0.1). It also reconfigures any installed browsers to use it as a proxy. Other software on the machine might also pick up the altered settings in Internet options and use it for proxy settings. When fiddler exits normally, it reverts the settings

This is why when

> if I use a proxy, I can make a request

And also why

> when I turn off my proxy, I can't make any request

If your app is stuck with the proxy settings as if fiddler is running but fiddler is not running, then no program is listening on port 8888. Ensure your request has an appropriate proxy setting for the relevant state of fiddler (I.e. No proxy set, if fiddler is not running) or if you're actually trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:8888 as the endpoint (i.e. Send requests to a proxy as if it were a destination server) then ensure fiddler is running

Comment: I would just like to be able to make a request to google.com, but I can't without using a proxy. I know that shouldn't be the case but I can't find what other config would have gotten it's proxy settings changed.

Comment: Open and then close fiddler; it will undo everything it has set. Restart visual studio, and be sure you're not setting a proxy manually in your code

Comment: I've completed all of the above with no result.

Comment: I ended up recreating my Visual Studio project to resolve the issue. I was not able to determine what the cause was though....

Comment: If you still have the old one, zip it up (minus the bin and obj folders) and put it somewhere downloadable (drop box, rapidshare etc) and paste a link.. I'll take a look and see if my machine behaves the same

Comment: So to resolve this issue, I ended up creating an entirely new VS project and copying over all of my classes. There must have been some configuration but I wasn't able to ever find it.

Comment: I'd have been whipping out a power text editor and doing a "find in files" for 8888 or similar, to check if it was still lurking somewhere. One would imagine it was, if dumping the property next and starting over didn't suffer the same side effects. Could also use a tool like BeyondCompare to diff the contents of the two folders ,,